# Ansible :Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

Tags: ssh, error-handling, ansible

I am new to `ansible`, got the below issue.
I was able to ssh into my client machine .but unable to run playbook.

Getting the error below:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source

 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit
localhost does not match 'all'

 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: a
```

here a is my group name. my hosts given below :

```
---------


[a]
172.31.26.93



[all:vars]

ansible_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant


 ansible_ssh_host=172.31.26.93
 ansible_ssh_port=22
 ansible_ssh_user='ansibleuser'
 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ansibleuser/.ssh
```

------- my playbook file given below ----

```
- hosts: a
  tasks:
  - name: create a directory
    file: path=/home/ansiblesuser/www state=directory
```

This is the first time I am getting this issue.

Comment: Hi Mani, welcome to SO! You didn't specify the file that contains your group name, nor the version of ansible you are using. Although if it is `/etc/ansible/hosts` and you have a modern version of ansible, you can check to see what ansible sees about that file using `ansible-inventory -i /path/to/the/inventory/file --list`

Comment: Separately, `ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/ansibleuser/.ssh` is incorrect as that points to a directory, and not to a _file_ -- unless you have for some terrible reason named your file as `.ssh` in `ansibleuser`'s home directory

Comment: I changed the ssh_priavtekey_file to /home/ansibleuser/.ssh/id_rsa. and tried the the commond ansible-inventory -i /path/to/the/inventory/file --list , got below response ...

Comment: {
 "_meta": {
  "hostvars": {
    "172.31.26.93": {
 "ansible_ssh_host": "172.31.26.93", 
        "ansible_ssh_pass": "vagrant", 
         "ansible_ssh_port": 22, 
         "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/home/ansibleuser/.ssh/id_rsa", 
         "ansible_ssh_user": "ansibleuser", 
         "ansible_user": "vagrant"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "a": {
        "hosts": [
            "172.31.26.93"
        ]
    }, 
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "a", 
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }, 
    "ungrouped": {}
}

Comment: ansible version is " 2.4.6.0"  and he file that contains your group name is "hosts"

Answer (score 25):

Before running the playbook just run the following command

```
ansible all --list-hosts
```

If the above error persists then go to `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and edit the `inventory` path which points to your specific host file.

Answer (score 22):

i had the same issue, the plugins ini and yaml were not enable in the ansible.cfg :

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = yaml, ini
```

Comment: You just saved me a solution for weeks of effort.  I could add a medal to this one.  If i had known what to search for i would have found it faster, lol.  
keyword = multiple hosts, combine dynamic and static hosts. e.g. `enable_plugins = aws_ec2, yaml, ini`, `inventory=./inventory` and all inventory files, including aws_ec2.yml inside inventory/

Answer (score 4):

I suddenly experienced the same issue with an inventory that was many years in use and hadn't changed recently.
It turned out I enabled a plugin which caused this issue.

I enabled the plugin vmware_vm_inventory which was the source of the message. This showed up by running `ansible-playbook -vvvv <host>`

I'd figured I should define the plugin in an ansible.cfg file that is present in the folder where I run playbooks that use this plugin and leave it out of the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Answer (score 1):

Host file with no read permissions caused the following error message:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Solution: change permissions

```
sudo chmod 744 /etc/ansible/hosts
```

In another occasion I got an error message due to an incorrect formatting of the hosts file:

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with yaml plugin: YAML
inventory has invalid structure, it should be a dictionary, got: <class
'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/hosts with ini plugin:
/etc/ansible/hosts:3: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: ;
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
```

and I fixed the issue by correcting the format error.

As suggested in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788531/2314737) check if hosts are available with

```
ansible all --list-hosts
```

Also check the actual location of the inventory file in the Ansible configuration file `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: Mine was extra "/" at start of path "roles/jenkins/inventory/hosts.ini" was enough

Comment: @mialdi98 yes sometimes it's not easy to figure out what's  wrong, Ansible error messages can be quite cryptic

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having this issue when you run

```
ansible-playbook -i path/to/inventory/file playbook.yml
```

Simply create an empty `ansible.cfg`  file in the directory where you have your playbook.

Answer (score 1):

Using ansible version ansible 2.9.27
able to resolve by giving complete (absolute path) for me error is like below

> [WARNING]: Unable to parse /root/hosts as an inventory source
> [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is
> available [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is
> available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all

Use following command

> `ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/hosts showfiles.yml`

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the problem for me:

1. Go to the root directory `/`
2. `cd etc` or `mkdir etc` and `cd etc`
3. `mkdir ansible` then `cd ansible`
4. `vi hosts` (then add the hosts)
5. `chmod 777 hosts`.
6. Check `ansible all -m ping`

Comment: He was asking about dynamic inventory with script. He was not asking about manual host update

Comment: A text file should not be chmod 777. It does not need execute permissions.

Comment: Read permissions should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7

this was causing above error:
*ansible-playbook -i host_test -v tasks.yml*

this fixed it:
*ansible-playbook -i **hosttest** -v tasks.yml*

Answer (score 0):

You'll see this error if the file doesn't exist on disk as well.

This will be in the `-vvvv` log:

```
Skipping due to inventory source not existing or not being readable by the current user
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the spaces around the `=` worked for me, Ansible managed to parse my *host.ini* file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mine was that, I try to commen someof the configuration. Which creates the problem. Just remove it and works fine.

I know its not specific solution of problem here, but just write it down to point out possible cause for other. Thanks